# What is pug mom?

Tags: meaning

What does "pug mom" mean?

(ex) I'm a single pug mom in a post grad program waiting tables & enjoying the struggle.

Does that mean 'working mom'?

Answer (score 3):

A [pug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pug) is a type of dog.

"Pug mom" means that she doesn't have any children, but she does have a pet dog that she perhaps thinks of as a child. There's an example of the broader phrase "dog mom" in [this National Geographic blog post](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2014/10/06/the-dog-moms-brain/).

Comment: That was a very quick answer. I didn't know the meaning of it. That's a quite interesting phrase. Thank you for your answer. ^^